# Finding the minimum of a function on a closed interval with Python

Tags: python, sympy

Updated: How do I find the minimum of a function on a closed interval [0,3.5] in Python? So far I found the max and min but am unsure how to filter out the minimum from here.

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

f = (x**3 / 3) - (2 * x**2) + (3 * x) + 1

fprime = f.diff(x)

all_solutions = [(xx, f.subs(x, xx)) for xx in sp.solve(fprime, x)]

print (all_solutions)
```

Comment: Are ```[0,3,5]``` *point* of the independent variable?

Comment: "Minimum" in the sense of lowest y value (global minimum) or derivative==0 (local minimum/stationary point)? ([more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point))

Answer (score 7):

Since [this PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16473) you should be able to do the following:

```
from sympy.calculus.util import *
f = (x**3 / 3) - (2 * x**2) - 3 * x + 1
ivl = Interval(0,3)
print(minimum(f, x, ivl))
print(maximum(f, x, ivl))
print(stationary_points(f, x, ivl))
```

Comment: ValueError: Interval(0, 3) is not a valid symbol

Comment: updated to show that symbol must be second arg

Comment: Is it possible to get both the minimum, and the x-value at which this minimum occurs using an in-built sympy function? I can "home brew" this kind of thing, but it feels like it would be nice if "minimum" returned a dictionary (say) with {xmin : ymin}

Comment: Not that I know of. HB might be the answer. I would do something like `f = lambda x: x**3-x-1; dict(zip(s:=stationary_points(f(x),x,S.Reals),map(f,s)))`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something like this

```
from sympy import solveset, symbols, Interval, Min
x = symbols('x')

lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = 3.5
function = (x**3/3) - (2*x**2) - 3*x + 1

zeros = solveset(function, x, domain=Interval(lower_bound, upper_bound))
assert zeros.is_FiniteSet # If there are infinite solutions the next line will hang.
ans = Min(function.subs(x, lower_bound), function.subs(x, upper_bound), *[function.subs(x, i) for i in zeros])
```

Comment: What libraries do you import for this solution?

Comment: Everything here comes from SymPy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using sympy:

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)

f = (x**3 / 3) - (2 * x**2) - 3 * x + 1
#f = 3 * x**4 - 4 * x**3 - 12 * x**2 + 3

fprime = f.diff(x)

all_solutions = [(xx, f.subs(x, xx)) for xx in sp.solve(fprime, x)]
interval = [0, 3.5]
interval_solutions = filter(
    lambda x: x[0] >= interval[0] and x[0] <= interval[1], all_solutions)

print(all_solutions)
print(interval_solutions)
```

`all_solutions` is giving you all points where the first derivative is zero, `interval_solutions` is constraining those solutions to a closed interval. This should give you some good clues to find minimums and maximums :-)

Comment: How does this solution account for the interval?

Comment: @TashayGreen Edited my answer to give you more clues

Comment: Can you explain to me where this "#f = 3 * x**4 - 4 * x**3 - 12 * x**2 + 3" comes from?

Comment: @TashayGreen That's another function to test the code was alright

Answer (score 0):

[image: Interactive Python session]

The f.subs commands show two ways of displaying the value of the given function at x=3.5, the first as a rational approximation, the second as the exact fraction.

[image: Graph produced by plot command]