# Is there a way to find a symbolical function’s vertical bounds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

Given a SymPy function `f(x)` and values `a`, `b` (`a != b`), is there a way to find the minimum and maximum value of `f(x)` on this interval? I’ve found some code for finding extremums that can be adapted for this purpose (split them into a min and max array, find lowest and highest respectively values with lambdify and use them), but surely there must be an easier way?

An alternative option would be using a `np.linspace`, but then I might miss out on exact values, which would be bad for things I have to do with them next.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192643/finding-the-minimum-of-a-function-on-a-closed-interval-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As now noted in the cited page, since [this PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16473) you should be able to do the following:

```
from sympy.calculus.util import *
f = (x**3 / 3) - (2 * x**2) - 3 * x + 1
ivl = Interval(0, 3)  # e.g. your (a, b)
print(minimum(f, ivl))
print(maximum(f, ivl))
```

Comment: Oh my God, I remember stumbling upon this page and somehow leaving it with an impression that this was turned down for some reason. Thank you!